# Where can I find the definition of attribute aliases in LDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap

**Context**

I'm trying to interact with an OpenLDAP server, and have some issues understanding the behavior of said server.

note : I don't have admin rights on this server, I am just writing some code that tries to extract lists of users and groups from it.

The specific point about which I have a question :

When I run a query asking for attribute `name`, I get entries containing `cn`, `sn` and `givenName`, and no `name` attribute :

```
# sample output:
$ ldapsearch [options ...] "(|(objectClass=posixAccount)(objectClass=posixGroup))" name
...
# sample users:
dn: uid=id4321,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
cn: u1234
sn: Doe
givenName: John

dn: uid=id4322,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
cn: u2234
sn: Doe
givenName: Jane

dn: ...

# sample groups:
dn: cn=Domain Users,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
cn: Domain Users

dn: cn=HR,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
cn: HR

dn: ...
```

**Question**

- Where can I find the correspondance "attribute name in the query" -> "attribute(s) name(s) in the response" ?
- If part of that correspondance is in the LDAP or OpenLDAP standard, where is it defined ?
- If part of that correspondance comes from the directory config/schema, how can I query for it ?

I have tried to Google with limited success, I'm trying to head to RFCs but I don't know which one to read first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question :

- the attributes `name`, `cn`, `sn` and a bunch of other standard attributes are defined in [RFC 4519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519)
- an attribute type may have a *supertype* (for example : the [definition of `cn`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-2.3) is `( 2.5.4.3 NAME 'cn' SUP name )`, the [definition of `sn`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-2.32) is `( 2.5.4.4 NAME 'sn' SUP name )` ), and if a search query queries for an attribute, the server may include in its response attributes whose *supertype* match
  so querying for `name` may return results with a `sn`, `cn`, `givenName` and `initials` attribute
- the definition of "attribute types" and "supertype" is in [RFC 4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.5.1)